# Moq in Microsoft Data Access Application Block

Tags: moq, data-access-app-block

I just downloaded the latest release of the source code to the Microsoft Enterprise Library.   When I tried to build the solution in Visual Studio 2010, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Moq' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

What is Moq and where can I find the assemblies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Moq (pronounced "Mock-you" or just
>   "Mock") is the only mocking library
>   for .NET developed from scratch to
>   take full advantage of .NET 3.5 (i.e.
>   Linq expression trees) and C# 3.0
>   features (i.e. lambda expressions)
>   that make it the most productive,
>   type-safe and refactoring-friendly
>   mocking library available. And it
>   supports mocking interfaces as well as
>   classes. Its API is extremely simple
>   and straightforward, and doesn't
>   require any prior knowledge or
>   experience with mocking concepts.

http://code.google.com/p/moq/

The assemblies are [here.](http://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list)  You probably want the 3.1 binaries.

Comment: There was a readme.txt file under EntLib50Src\Lib\ThirdParty\Moq that explains how to get the MOQ assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Beside downloading DLL files from  http://code.google.com/p/moq/ you need to add them in the bin reference  of your application in VS.In VS ,right click on References and choose Add Reference.